# Installing the Facebook apk to the android emulator

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to install the Facebook apk to my android emulator as per: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started. I use the command:

```
adb install <path>/Facebook-11.apk
```

It starts okay. After a while i get

```
255KB/s (40683138 bytes in 155.495s)
pkg: /data/local/tmp/Facebook-11.apk
```

And then it just seems to hang on that. It has been stuck there for a good while now. How long should this take? I read it should only take a few minutes. Is there any way to check if something has gone wrong?

Comment: I think there might be less memory declared or available in emulator. try adding or checking memory space available. I'm not telling you exactly.. this may be a scenario

Comment: when I use `adb install Facebook-11.apk` my terminal just seems to hang.

Answer (score 0):

i increased the VM heap to 50mb and it worked. it was just the memory problem although i think 50 mb is more than enough

Comment: Is that 50 megabit (50 Mb, i.e. 50 000 000 bits), 50 megabyte (50 MB, i.e. 50 000 000 bytes)?